# About tens of Firestore collections have the same access rule, must I repeat writing same `match` sentence for each collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

the match I'm using is below

```
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
```

but firebase always sends alarm, so I want to modify rules.
if a match sentence for a collect, the repeat will be too much.

so I wonder if there is any solution to avoid repeat?

Comment: You can use wildcard on collection name like `match /{collectionName}/{docId}` and then `allow read: if collectionName in ["c1", "c2"]` but this rule then gets applied to all the collections.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to add same rule to multiple collections would be to use a wildcard on collection name as shown below:

```
match /{collectionName}/{docId} {
  allow read: if collectionName in ["colName1", "colName2"];
}
```

However, this rule is applied to all the collections so if you have any exceptions (e.g. colName3) make sure you define rules for those collections separately as this rule will reject reads for colName3.